# HTML5 canvas intellisense in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

is there a way to get intellisense for the HTML5 canvas element? In VS Code 0.7.10 when I write in my JS code this:

```
context = document.getElementById(canvasId).getContext('2d');
```

then when I write

```
context.
```

I do not have any intellisense help for my context.

Thanks.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

VS Code can support it!

Just tell VS Code what type is the `context`. Adding the following code on your variable then the VS Code will know what it is. Sorry that I don't have enough point to post the image. Just click the `solution` to see how it works.

`/** @type {CanvasRenderingContext2D} */`

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14Lj2.png)

Answer (score 14):

That's currently not supported by VS Code and it is hard to fix. Because JavaScript lacks type annotations, VS Code tries to flow types as good as possible. In your example `document.getElementById` breaks this flow because from the spec it can return any html element (and we have no further knowledge of the html structure or the value of `canvasId`).

Something like this, would be more favourable to VS Code:

`var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.|`

Alternative, you could look into using TypeScript because there you use type annotations and type casting.

Comment: Outdated answer. You should use one of the new ones as they work best.

Answer (score 13):

I use the "type cast":

```
var canvas = /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */ (document.querySelector('#canvas'))
```

and then enjoy basic Intellisense:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to re-declare @type variable and assign ctx to get the intellisense working again when you pass ctx as argument in another function. this worked for me in react :

```
const drawGame=(ctx)=>{
     /** @type {CanvasRenderingContext2D} */
    var dgCtx = ctx
    dgCtx.fillStyle = "#79d70e"
    dgCtx.fillRect(0,0,gs.width, gs.height)
}

useEffect(()=>{
    const canvas = canvasRef.current
    /** @type {CanvasRenderingContext2D} */
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
    drawGame(ctx)
},[])
```